# Realurl not configurated correctly

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-news, realurl

My news link look like this: `?tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=282&cHash=` I am using realurl autoconfig. I do not know how to setup a realurl_config by myself. I often get an error message. Maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

There is a complete chapter for [realurl configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/7.3/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html) in the manual of `ext:news`.

Switch your realurl config to `PHP source`, then edit the config file and add the code from the news manual.

You also find examples for configuring `ext:news` in the [manual of realurl](https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Configuration-reference#fixedpostvars)

Comment: So I deactivate the autoconfig setting. Then I create a realurl config php data with the basic setup. There I have to add the fixedPostVars, right?

Comment: let the autoconfig generate a basic setting in plain php. it is easier to enhance.

Comment: I cant find my UID for newsDetailConfiguration

Comment: It's the page `uid` where the news will be displayed. Detail page. If you only have one page for the news plugin your list view and your detail view are on the same page.

Comment: And where do i get the UIDs for '71' => 'newsTagConfiguration',
                '72' => 'newsCategoryConfiguration',?

Comment: if you don't use news tags and news categories you don't need them. otherwise it are the pages where the user can select news by tag or category, which then can be reflected in the url.